# I can’t login using facebook account kit using php

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, registration, account

I have tried many times for login with sms facebook account kit but after verifying nothing happening.
I am not able to insert the data into database.
I followed a tutorial in this address 
https://www.aurigait.com/blog/facebook-account-kit-single-signon-sso/

Everytime I am getting otp and able to verify but after that it is just redirecting to index.php page.
I am looking for login and registration using php and facebook account kit. please do anybody help please.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fb test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  <script
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
      background: #EEE;
    }
    .mdl-switch {width:auto;}
    .btnfull {width: 100%;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-offset">
      <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
          <h1 class="mdl-typography--title">Facebook Account Kit Demo</h1>
      <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['username'])):
      ?>
      <p>Hello <?=$_SESSION['username']?>. You're logged In.</p>
      <p><a href="response.php?logout=true">Logout</a>
      <?php
      else:
      ?>
      <div id="block_login">
        <form method="post" action="response.php" id="frm_login">          
          <input type="hidden" name="login"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="code" id="login_code"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="login_via" id="login_via"/>
        </form>


        <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
          <li class="mdl-list__item">
            <button onclick="loginWithSMS();" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-typography--text-center btnfull">Login By SMS</button>
          </li>
          <li class="mdl-list__item">
                <button onclick="loginWithEmail();" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent mdl-typography--text-center btnfull">Login By Email</button>
          </li>
        </ul>


      </div>


      <?php endif; ?>


      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
    // initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
    AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
      AccountKit.init ({
          appId:"you_app_id_here",
          state:"you_Account_kit_client_token_here",
          version:"your_account_kit_api_version",
          debug: true
});
    };


    // login callback
    function loginCallback(response) {
      if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
        document.getElementById("login_code").value = response.code;
        document.getElementById("frm_login").submit();
      }
      else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
        alert("Auth failure");
        return false;
      }
      else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
        alert("BAD_PARAMS");
        return false;
      }
    }


    function loginWithSMS(){
      document.getElementById("login_via").value = 1;
      AccountKit.login("PHONE",{}, loginCallback);
    }


    function loginWithEmail(){
      document.getElementById("login_via").value = 2;
      AccountKit.login("EMAIL", {}, loginCallback);
    }


  </script>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['message']) && !empty($_SESSION['message'])){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('".$_SESSION['message']."');</script>";
  $_SESSION['message'] = '';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**response.php code**

```
<?
    $dbname = 'dbname';
    $dbuser = 'dbuser';
    $dbpwd = 'dbpwd';
    $dbhost = 'localhost';


    $facebook_app_id = "facebook_app_id";
    $app_secret = "app_secret";


    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname);


    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }


    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
      $login_via = $_POST['login_via'];
      $code = $_POST['code'];


      /* Get Account data via Graph */
      $graph_url = "https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/access_token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=".$code."&access_token=AA|".$facebook_app_id."|".$app_secret;
      $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url), true);
      if($result['id']){
        $account_id = $result['id'];
        $account_url = "https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/me/?access_token=".$result['access_token'];
        $account_data = json_decode(hitCurl($account_url), true);
        if(isset($account_data['phone'])){
          $country_code = '+'.$account_data['phone']['country_prefix'];
          $mobile = $account_data['phone']['national_number'];
        } elseif(isset($account_data['email'])){
          $email = $account_data['email']['address'];
        }
        if($login_via == 1){
          $q = "SELECT * FROM `users` where country_code='".$country_code."' AND mobile='".$mobile."'";
        } else {
          $q = "SELECT * FROM `users` where email='".$email."'";
        }  
        $rs = $mysqli->query($q);
        $row_count = $rs->num_rows;
        if($row_count)
        {
          $user = $rs->fetch_assoc();
          if($user['name'])
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['name'];
          elseif($user['mobile'])
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user['mobile'];
          elseif($user['email'])
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user['email'];
        } else {
          $q1 = "INSERT INTO `test`.`users` (`id`, `name`, `country_code`, `mobile`, `email`, `account_id`) VALUES (NULL, '', '".@$country_code."', '".@$mobile."', '".@$email."', '".@$account_id."')";
          $row1 = $mysqli->query($q1);
          if($row1){
            $msg = "You are successfully registered & logged In. Please complete your profile. Id: ".$mysqli->insert_id;
            if($login_via == 1){
                  $_SESSION['username'] = $mobile;
            } else {
                  $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
            }      
          } else {
                $msg = 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
          }
          $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
        }
      } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Some error. Try Again!";
      }
      /**/


      header('Location: index.php');
      exit(0);
    }


    function hitCurl($url){
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

**Table code**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What error messages are you getting? (Hope you are aware that you will probably not get any shown, if the message could happen to contain a newline, because then you’d be creating invalid JS code.)

Comment: I am able to get the sms and verify it but after verification it redirects to index.php and values are not inserting to mysql database

Comment: Well then either it did not go into the if/else branches you expected to begin with, or your attempt at inserting the data itself caused an error. Suggest you start by outputting error messages directly, and removing the redirect, so that you can begin to debug this properly ...